# Missing element of an array after loop and conditions. Result in an array with 3 elements instead of 4. 4 instead of 5, so on

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, max, min

You could call it a homework problem.  I am doing a CodeWar challenge, basically, I get a string of numbers and I am supposed to return maximum and minimum values.  I got this close of completing this problem but there is an issue.  For example, "1 2 3 4 555" should return "555 1".  I know about `max` and `min` functions but I don't need this yet.

I created a for loop for every x in a list of given string I made.  For example `"1 2 3 4 555"` changed to list `["1", " ", "2", " ", "3", " ", "4", " ", "5", "5", "5"]`.  I have nested some `if` statements to add x or a number in string to new array with a few conditions.  `["1", " ", "2", " ", "3", " ", "4", " ", "5", "5", "5"]` --> `[1, 2, 3, 555]`.  Instead I get `[1, 2, 3]`.  I have gotten `[1, 2, 3, 555]` or any array without missing an element, now this.

This is my code.  I want `[1, 2, 3, 555]` instead of `[1, 2, 3]`.  Then I will use `max` and `min` functions to get min and max values.

```py
def high_and_low(numbers):

  numbers = numbers

  toList = list(numbers)
  print(toList)

  newList = []
  string = ''

  for x in toList:
    if x != ' ': #number
      string += x
      print(string)
    else: #elif x == ' ': #anything that's not a number.  Space for example
      newList.append(int(string)) #we 'add' number to new list before space.  Converted number string to integar.

      #then

      string = '' #reset to empty so we can add next number to empty without worrying about adding number we do not need.
    print(newList) #[1,2,3] instead of [1, 2, 3, 555] is what I wanted.  If I called high_and_low("1 2 3 555 3"), I can get [1, 2, 3, 555]

high_and_low("1 2 3 555")  # return "555 1"
```

Same code without comments:

```py
def high_and_low(numbers):

  numbers = numbers

  toList = list(numbers)
  print(toList)

  newList = []
  string = ''

  for x in toList:
    if x != ' ':
      string += x
      print(string)
    else: #elif x == ' ':
      newList.append(int(string))
      string = ''

    print(newList)

high_and_low("1 2 3 555")  # return "555 1"
```

I expect the output of `[1, 2, 3, 555]`, but the actual output is `[1, 2, 3]`.  If I called `high_and_low("1 2 3 555 3")`, I can get `[1, 2, 3, 555]`.

Comment: Why not `numbers = "1 2 3 555".split()
print(numbers) # ['1', '2', '3', '555']`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the `list()`, I would suggest the `str.split()` function instead. This splits a string into a list by a delimiter (i.e. a character that separates the desired parts of the string).

So in your example consider using something along the lines of this:

```
toList = numbers.split( ' ' )
```

The line tells Python to split your string, `numbers`, with the space delimiter, `' '`, and store it into a list, `toList`.

Comment: that's neat... but you will also need to convert these numbers from `str` to `int`. You can do that simply by using `map`

Comment: `max(numbers, key=int)`